# How do I format the initialization string for an extremely old date (around year 0 CE) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, utc

I want to represent the year 0 in JavaScript, not 1970 which as we know is the actual year zero. I want to know how to correctly format this or any date string with an unusually small number of years. I tried initializing it with `new Date('0000-00-00T00:00:00')` and also with `new Date('0-00-00T00:00:00')`, but both times the toString method said 'Invalid Date'.

I just realized I can get around this by using the year 1970 and offsetting it, so it's not really mission critical, but supposedly JavaScript can do really small and really big years, over plus or minus 200,000. I find it odd and dumb that implementations of it don't seem to support initializing dates in one of the standard ways for all of the years in its range. I find a lot of things in JavaScript odd, dumb, and inconsistent, honestly, some of it due to individual implementations no doubt, but my opinion remains unchanged.

Ok now that I've insulted the language, you may proceed to enlighten me if there's some way to do this.

Comment: The [ECMAScript Date range](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-time-values-and-time-range) is fixed to exactly ±100,000,000 days from 1970-01-01, which is about ±285,426 years. :-)

Answer (score 1):

K I figured it out. I was being inconsistent and dumb! And so was JavaScript. It's not blameless.

Years, hours, minutes and seconds can be zero, but the months and days start at 1. I simply have to make my default month and day 01 and not 00.

Comment: If 0000-00-00 date existed that would mean that a month starts with day 0 instead of day 1 and year starts with month 0. This means June 5 2020 has to be written as `2020-05-04`. I would not be happy with that...

Comment: @Gherman yeah, I noticed that. I was thinking in terms of 0 indexing for everything haha!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```js
var date = new Date();
date.setFullYear(0);
var year = date.getFullYear();
alert(year);
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes that would definitely work, I hadn't thought of that. I seem to have found another way to do it though. I was thinking about the days and months wrong, forgot that humans start days at 1. Glad I'm not one of them.

Comment: A pleasure, im glad this is usefull for you

Comment: if you want you can give me that thumbs up and i would glad, thanks